# f# iterating : The type 'unit' does not match the type 'char'

Tags: f#, unit-type

I have this function

```
let items = ['a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'b'; 'b'; 'a'; 'a'; 'c'; 'd'; 'd'; 'e'; 'e';] 

open System
let rng = new Random()

let randomSelect list toget = let randomList k len = List.init k (fun _ -> rng.Next(1,len))
                              let getK l k = List.nth l k 
                              let primeGet = getK list
                              List.length list
                              |> randomList toget 
                              |> List.iter (fun i -> primeGet i) 

let res23 = randomSelect items 3
```

but for some reason the function is expecting a unit list, not a generic one

The type 'unit' does not match the type 'char'

why is this happening ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others already pointed out, you probably wanted to use `map` instead of `iter`. That would work, but it wouldn't be particularly efficient implementation. Here is an alternative way to implement it using list comprehensions:

```
let randomSelect list toget = 
  [ let arr = list |> Array.ofList
    for _ in 1 .. toget do 
      yield arr.[rng.Next(arr.Length)] ]
```

... which could be also written using the `map` function, but I find the comprehension syntax more readable:

```
let randomSelect list toget = 
  let arr = list |> Array.ofList
  [ 1 .. toget ] |> List.map (fun _ -> arr.[rng.Next(arr.Length)] )
```

To avoid the problem with indexing, the function first converts the list (given as an argument) to array. This will be more efficient if you need to take larger number of elements. For smaller number of elements, using just list and indexing using `List.nth` should be fine.

The snippet then generates a sequence of the right length (using `1 .. toget`) and generates a new random element for every element in this input sequence. The values from the input sequence are not needed - they are just use to generate some sequence to start with.

Answer (score 4):

Because `List.iter` expects a function which returns `unit` and the function `fun i -> primeGet i` returns `unit` if and only if `list` is a list of `unit`.

Note that even if your code did compile, it wouldn't do anything, because `List.iter` returns `unit` and is only used for the function's side-effects, which in this case don't exist. My guess is you probably want to use `map` instead of `iter`, which returns a list with the results of `primeGet`. This would also fix your type error.

Answer (score 0):

One comment:

```
  let getK l k = List.nth l k 
  let primeGet = getK list
```

`List.nth` is a linear operation. Because F# List is a linked list, it does not have a notion of position. and in your code `primeGet` is used in a loop, that makes your the running time of your code quadratic.

Comment: I know it is not efficient at all. but i want to get it work firstm then make it better